# Styling the width of non-breaking spaces

Tags: css

I'd like to make my non-breaking spaces narrower for use with French punctuation, preferably without resorting to lowering `font-size`.

Here's what I tried:

```html
Text<span class"sp-thin-fr">&nbsp;</span>?
```

```css
span.sp-thin-fr {
    display: inline-block;
    width:   0.125em;  /* 1/8 em */
    }
```

The problem is that `display: inline-block` for some reason overrides the non-breaking property of nbsp (tested in Firefox, Chrome and IE 11).

Can anyone think of another way of doing this, without putting the characters around the space in spans with `white-space: nowrap` applied? (Note that I'd like to be able to set the *exact* width for the space.)

Comment: letter-spacing?? like maybe, letter-spacing: 0px; http://jsfiddle.net/rkbkbq8q/ You can even set a negative value.

Comment: @jonny.milano - Add some code and submit it as an answer.

Comment: I thought about it, but then there wouldn't be any spaces when copying the text from the web, and the expected thing for French documents is to have normal non-breaking spaces before punctuation (`<hush>`they're very touchy about that`</hush>`)

Comment: Disregard the above comment; I missed that nbsp and thought you put span around last letter and question mark.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use `display:inline-block`.

`letter-spacing` would probably work here. So:

```
span.sp-thin-fr { letter-spacing: 0px; }
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rkbkbq8q/

Comment: Actually, I think `margin-right` would probably be a better idea in this case, because the [CSS3 draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text-3/#letter-spacing-property) that applying `letter-spacing` to an element containing only a single character has no effect on the rendered result. But that still leaves me with the problem of exact sizing.

Comment: Well I'll be.. Hey! You answered your own question! :)

Comment: yeah, well, not really. I considered it before, but I cant set the exact desired width that way cause every font has a space of slightly different size and I'd need to calculate the offset based on it. The Unicode guys really screwed things up for typographers when they didn't include non-breaking variant for each of the spaces.

Comment: Hmm... Didn't think about the fonts having different space widths. Maybe use 'rem' units instead of pixels, then the measurement would be more relative to the actual individual font, like: letter-spacing: -0.1rem; /* or zero */ It's a tough question. Kinda why I commented originally and didn't post an answer directly ;)